# ksh: translate unix path to windows path with sed and place in variable

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sed, ksh

Run this at a KornShell (ksh):

```
echo ${MYVAR} | sed 's/\//\\/g'
```

It works fine if MYVAR is //myserver/myshare
But doing the same and trying to put it into a variable and it fails with 
sed: newline or end of file found in pattern

```
UNCVAR=`echo ${MYVAR} | sed 's/\//\\/g'`
```

How do I properly convert this path from the UNIX style slashes to the windows style slashes?

Important sample data:

```
//QFLELSAMPLE/reports
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another reason to stop using backticks (unless you plan to be using the Bourne Shell on Solaris/HP/et.al.) Backticks are deprecated according 'The New Kornshell programming Language', published in 1995!

```
MYVAR="//myserver/myshare"
UNCVAR=$(echo ${MYVAR} | sed 's/\//\\/g')
echo "$UNCVAR"
\\myserver\myshare
```

Notice that I'm using the `$( cmd )` version of command substitution.

I hope this helps.

Comment: On my system (mks toolkit running on windows server) I get \myserver\myshare for that.  It is eating the first backslash.  But I revised the question with the input I am using and that causes the \r to be interpreted as a ctrl M which throws off the output completely.  So I'm losing the first backslash and the third backslash.  Seems like I should just need to escape those backslashes.  If I double them I get the correct output.  So thanks.

Comment: Wow, had forgot about mkstoolkit (although I loved it 10+ years ago!) Just for interest's sake, please try my solution but with `echo $"$UNCVAR" . Thanks for the points!

Answer (score 0):

Full solution: Use $() instead of `` and double the backslashes to escape them from echo.

```
MYVAR="//QFLELSAMPLE/reports"
UNCVAR=$(echo ${MYVAR} | sed 's/\//\\\\/g')
echo "$UNCVAR"
```

Weird though that if you then export UNCVAR and view it via set it has the value:

```
\\\\\\\\QFLELITE38\\\\reports
```

Which seems to have double the expected backslashes.
But passing the variable through echo gives the correct number which is what I'm after.